# Do Jira/Confluence Data Center Edition support master-master database cluster?

Tags: database, postgresql, jira, high-availability, confluence

For a large database cluster, using [BDR3](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/postgres-bdr-2ndquadrant/) building HA master-master replication globally, can Jira/Confluence Date Center Edition work well with it?

Comment: Hi, this looks like a request that would be best addressed to the vendor of the product in question, rather than a programming question that would be on topic for this site. Have a look at the [help] for more information on what this site is and isn't for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of, as of 2020 at least